# How to make button on Bootstrap 4 card border?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there any way using css to make a button for a Bootstrap card that will be on card's border? As in the picture below:

[image]

I was browsing the documentation and I don't see that it is possible directly using Bootstrap 4. Maybe it can be styled in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.card .btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can get this by adding the following properties to the button:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
```